# Application not running in apple watch simulator due to bundle identifier issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, apple-watch

I'm building an apple watch application for which i created a AppGroup and also setting the provisioning profile and the certificate.

Now the issue is while building/running the "watchkit app" xcode is throwing an error saying,

```
warning: Capabilities that require entitlements from “appname WatchKit Extension/appname WatchKit Extension.entitlements" may not function in the Simulator because the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“WatchKitProfile”) has an AppID of “com.id.watchApp” which does not match your bundle identifier “com.id.watchApp.watchkitextension”.
```

and nothing is showing in the applewatch simulator.But application is working fine in iPhone simulator.

Even the applewatch methods are not calling `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication`

One more doubt, I'm using the appgroup which already used by other members.Will this create any problem or is this the issue for this warning.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an App ID, you need to regenerate your provisioning profiles because they will not have the newly created App ID listed.  Xcode can do this for you automatically as a "Fix Issue" prompt.

Ensure once you have created your App ID, you add it both the main app and the watch kit app extension via the capabilities tab and click on Fix Issues until it is all ok.